# "That's great." Is "great" here an adjective or an adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

```
"I cleared the exam."
"That's great."
```

Is 'great' used here considered an adjective or an adverb?

An adjective defines a noun while an adverb is related to a verb.

My belief is that here it refers to the event of the person passing the exam so it must be an adjective.
Is this correct?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Who knows?  It's in the great tradition of driveby downvoting on this site.  I'll guess that it means your question is too simple to be worthy of the attention of the lofty.  And you already knew the answer.

Comment: I knew the answer, I used this somewhere, I got called out for saying it was an adjective in this particular scenario, I couldn't find this particular usage on Google, so I looked here for confirmation. Also, thanks for restoring the vote balance, if it was you.

Comment: Whether it refers to the event of the person passing the exam or not has no bearing on what "great" is. Furthermore, do you know how an adjective and adverb function? It is better to explain why it can be considered as an adverb if you don't want your question to get downvoted more. *An adjective defines a noun while adverb is related to a verb* is not always right.

Comment: What were your doubts? It's no different to _The examination was great_. There's a full answer below from PaulM which I'd go along with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A: *I cleared the exam.*

B: *That's great*

"Great" is an adjective here; it is subjective predicative complement of the verb "be". It's called 'subjective' because it is ascribing the property of being "great" to the subject "that", which happens to be anaphoric to the preceding sentence. In other words A's utterance is the antecedent for B's "that", which refers to the situation that A has described.